# Kibana relative time set only to Now

Tags: elasticsearch, time, kibana, kibana-4

I cannot change the relative time frame to different end times beside now.

How can I change it to 3mo ago - 2mo ago?

1. OS:

   - Ubuntu 14.04 / Chrome Version 50.0.2661.75 (64-bit)
   - Mac OSx 10.11.4 / Chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit)
2. Kibana

   - Version   4.3.1
   - Build 9517
   - Commit SHA    d6e412d

[image]

Comment: You can use Absolute option to achieve the same!

Comment: but it wold be static. I want it dynamic, relative to the current date.
I know this option is available, but for some reason, not on my instance.